# ASP.Net Core 2.2 wwwroot static content hosted on S3 and CloudFront

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-content, wwwroot

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.2 and would like to host wwwroot static content on AWS S3 served by CloudFront. Haven't found anything on Google so posted the question here. I am familiar with AWS S3 and Cloudfront. I only need to find out how / what to change in ASP.Net Core razor application. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using rewrite rules in my server (IIS).
In order to do that you add a new IIS Url Rewrite module rule under system.webServer section in web.config.
Also, if you host your app in Apache/Nginx, there is a possibility to configure redirect rule based on configuration file with server-specific syntax.
Following is a sample rule, it redirects all resources starting with "media" to CloudFront distribution.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Media to CDN" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="media/*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://<my_cloudfront_id>.cloudfront.net/media/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: How to accomplish this for Kestrel?